# How to design a GET HTTP request without knowing in advance the number of arguments?

Tags: django, http, get

I am toying with a little arduino project: a wifi scanner.

The device scans all available wifi networks and sends data to a web server. The data are {SSID, RSSI, MAC} for each signal.

In order to reduce power consumption, I want the device to send only one GET request to my server.

Something like : mywebpage.com/incomingData/VERIZON/13/361728/iphone/40/2820240/
(Here I have two networks.)

But I don't know in advance the number of networks!

How would you handle this design situation?

Comment: send the data as json or xml or some other serialized format

Comment: json format is a good idea, but I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body?lq=1 and I am wondering if it wouldn't be better to pass the json as a body in a POST request

Comment: yeah, doing it in a post rather than a get would be better